# Combine @State and @StateObject

Tags: swiftui

I have a class `Data` with some fields:

```
public class Data: NSObject, Identifiable {
    public var favourite: Bool?
    // + some other fields
}
```

I declare it in the main view like this:

```
   // parent view
   @State var data: Data?
```

Then I pass it to a child view, where it's being accepted as a binding:

```
   // child view
   @Binding var data: Data?
```

My intention is that by default, `data` is absent. But then I may populate it with some instance in the parent view - and the child view will get updated. And the other way around: when I assign another instance to `data` in the child view, my parent view also gets updated. So it works both ways, as expected.

Now, I would like to trigger a parent view update not just when the whole `data` gets reasigned, but when one of its properties gets changed. This doesn't work as is: if I change a property of `data` in the child view, it doesn't trigger the parent view update, which is expected behavior, AFAIK.

So, I've learned that I have to use a combination of `@StateObject` / `@ObservedObject` instead, in order to achieve this (and mark the fields of `Data` as `@Published`). So, I've updated the `Data` class as following:

```
public class Data: NSObject, ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    @Published public var favourite: Bool?
    // + some other fields
}
```

And then I tried to change `@State` to `@StateObject` and `@Binding` to `@ObservedObject` correspondingly. However, if I do this, I lose the original behavior, because `@StateObject` imposes a `let` constraint (makes the field immutable), so it won't be possible to reassign the `data` itself anymore. Also, `@StateObject` doesn't work with optionals, so I can't have `Data` anymore - I must have `Data?` instead, which defeats the logic I'm trying to implement.

And this is where I, being new to SwiftUI, got really confused. How do I achieve both behaviors at the same time? Or is it not even possible? Or, maybe, it is, but it's a "bad practice"? Any suggestions?

In theory, if my understanding is correct, I could live with `@StateObject` / `@ObservedObject`, having to reassign all internal fields of `data` instead of reassigning the whole `data`. However, I find it pretty cumbersome and would prefer some other option, if it's available.

Comment: If you need an `Optional`, make a field of your `ObservableObject` `Optional` -- you don't need the whole thing to be an `Optional`.

Comment: Well, I kind of do need the whole thing as optional, because in the beginning it’s absent and it’s being pulled from elsewhere (API).

Comment: Right, so you have something like this (formatting is bad in comments, sorry): `class MyObservable: ObservableObject { @Published var dataFromServer: MyData? }`

Comment: And `MyData / dataFromServer` should probably be a `struct`

Comment: I've updated the question with more examples :)

Comment: I'd suggest checking out the Apple or Hacking with Swift SwiftUI tutorials to see some examples of how data management is handled. Until Xcode 15, this is most often handled with a `@StateObject` that holds `struct`-based data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've managed to solve it by implementing the idea pitched by @jnpdx.

Basically, I had to create a wrapper around `Data` - I called it `ObservableData`. It looks pretty much like this:

```
public class ObservableData : ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: Data?
    
    var favourite: Bool {
        get {
            data?.favourite ?? false
        }
        set {
            data?.favourite = newValue
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.objectWillChange.send()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have it as `@StateObject` in my main view - and as `@ObservedObject` in secondary views.

The important part here is `self.objectWillChange.send()`, which notifies the system about updates in the fields of the wrapped object.

Having this, I can achieve both behaviors: my views are getting updated when I reassign the whole `data` structure - **and** when I reassign particular fields (also, `data` is optional, just as I needed it).

Comment: You may already be aware, but just in case: if your model were a `struct`, you could avoid having to do the `objectWillChange` -- `@Published` would know to update automatically.

Comment: Thanks, but in my particular case `Data` must conform to a specific class-protocol, so I can't have it as a `struct`. I just didn't want to pollute the question with this detail.